# GDB issue on Mac catalina

Tags: macos, gdb, macos-catalina

I bought the new mac 16" and I have a C program to debug. First, I wanted to use valgrind but it seems that there's no available version of it for Catalina at the moment. I wanted to to use gdb then but when I launch `gdb my_file` I've got this messages :

```
warning: dsym file UUID doesn't match the one in /Users/my_name/Downloads/CPE_pushswap_2019/push_swap

warning: `/Users/my_name/Downloads/CPE_pushswap_2019/src/atribut.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/Users/my_name/Downloads/CPE_pushswap_2019/src/atribut_2.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/Users/my_name/Downloads/CPE_pushswap_2019/src/choose_algo.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/Users/my_name/Downloads/CPE_pushswap_2019/src/main.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/Users/my_name/Downloads/CPE_pushswap_2019/src/my_rev_list.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/Users/my_name/Downloads/CPE_pushswap_2019/src/params_to_list.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
(No debugging symbols found in push_swap)
Attaching to program: /Users/my_name/Downloads/CPE_pushswap_2019/push_swap, process 10
Can't attach to process 10: No such process (3)
/Users/my_name/Downloads/CPE_pushswap_2019/10: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

I don't know what to do to solve this. (if anyone know a way to install valgrind on catalina too I'm open to idea thx)

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please note that you expose your user name in the warning messages which may be a privacy issue.

Comment: AFAIK Mac OS uses clang compiler infrastructure and the according debugger is `lldb` so try `lldb my_file` instead. Regarding the missing debugging symbols (if `gdb` should be correct): Have you compiled with debugging symbols? If the debugging symbols stored in separate file you can tell `gdb` the directory of the symbol files via the `directory` command in `gdb`.